# Cut tows off the dataframe based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example data :

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({
    'file': ['file1','file2','file3','file4','file5','file6','file7','file8','file9'],
    'prop1': [True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],
    'prop2': [False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,False],
    'prop3': [False,True,False,True,False,True,False,False,True]
})
```

```
file    prop1   prop2   prop3
0   file1   True    False   False
1   file2   False   False   True
2   file3   False   False   False
3   file4   False   False   True
4   file5   False   False   False
5   file6   False   False   True
6   file7   False   False   False
7   file8   False   True    False
8   file9   False   False   True
```

I need to cut off (after cutting they shouldnt be in 'dd' dataframe) all rows with false prop values (in example file 3, 5, 7) to another new dataframe

Comment: Can you explain more, why not removed `file1` ?

Comment: because file1 prop1 = true, i need to cut files where prop1 = false, prop2 = false, prop3 = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` per columns with columns names in list:

```
mask = dd[['prop1','prop2','prop3']].any(axis=1)
```

Or all columns without first:

```
mask = dd.iloc[:, 1:].any(axis=1)
```

Or with columns with `prop` in column names:

```
mask = dd.filter(like='prop').any(axis=1)
```

---

```
df1 = dd[mask]
```

If need removed rows use `~` for invert boolean mask:

```
df2 = dd[~mask]

print (df1)
    file  prop1  prop2  prop3
0  file1   True  False  False
1  file2  False  False   True
3  file4  False  False   True
5  file6  False  False   True
7  file8  False   True  False
8  file9  False  False   True

print (df2)
    file  prop1  prop2  prop3
2  file3  False  False  False
4  file5  False  False  False
6  file7  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 1):

> simple application of morgan laws using [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

**Getting the lines that do not have False**

You need [DataFrame.any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
dd[dd[['prop1','prop2','prop3']].any(axis=1)]
```

Or using [DataFrame.all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
dd[~(~dd[['prop1','prop2','prop3']]).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
    file  prop1  prop2  prop3
0  file1   True  False  False
1  file2  False  False   True
3  file4  False  False   True
5  file6  False  False   True
7  file8  False   True  False
8  file9  False  False   True
```

---

**Getting the lines that have False**

```
dd[~dd[['prop1','prop2','prop3']].any(axis=1)]
```

Or using [DataFrame.all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
dd[(~dd[['prop1','prop2','prop3']]).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
    file  prop1  prop2  prop3
2  file3  False  False  False
4  file5  False  False  False
6  file7  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(dd.loc[set(dd.index) - set(dd.query('prop1 == False and prop2 == False and prop3 == False ').index), :])

    file  prop1  prop2  prop3
0  file1   True  False  False
1  file2  False  False   True
3  file4  False  False   True
5  file6  False  False   True
7  file8  False   True  False
8  file9  False  False   True
```